# How to find and replace the first match of a pattern in each line of a file in BASH?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I need to find and replace the first appearance of `,` on each line of a file with `1,`, e.g.:

```
0001,mountain,a big rock
0002,tree,a tall plant
0003,whale,a big fish
0004,lion,a big cat
0005,iPhone,a small computer
```

The output would look like:

```
00011,mountain,a big rock
00021,tree,a tall plant
00031,whale,a big fish
00041,lion,a big cat
00051,iPhone,a small computer
```

The only solution I know involves using a while loop that takes a very long time for long files:

```
while read -r line
do
    sed -i 's/,/1,/' file.csv
done < file.csv
```

How can I find and replace the first match of a pattern on each line in a file?

Comment: Your while loop makes no sense. It's completely unneeded. Just use the sed command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loop is unnecessary. Just run the sed command without the loop and it will process the entire file in one go.

```
sed -i 's/,/1,/' file.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in pure Bash with:

```
new_lines=()
while IFS= read -r line || [[ $line ]] ; do
    new_lines+=( "${line/,/1,}" )
done <file.csv
printf '%s\n' "${new_lines[@]}" >file.csv
```

Set IFS and use the '-r' option to 'read' to ensure that lines are read correctly.

Test '[[ $line ]]' to allow for 'read' returning FALSE after reading an unterminated final line.

However, this solution reads the whole file into memory, and benchmarking on Cygwin shows that it is 100 times slower than the pure 'sed' solution.  It's probably only practical for files up to around ten thousand lines long.

If you are dealing with very large files, other tools might be significantly faster than 'sed'.  A possible 'perl' solution is:

```
perl -i -ple 's/,/1,/' file.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to *edit* the file, why not use `ed`, the standard editor?

```
ed -s file < <(printf '%s\n' ',s/,/1,/' 'wq')
```

The `,s/,1,/` tells `ed` to perform the substitution `s/,/1,/` on every line (`,` is a shorthand for the whole file `1,$`). Then, `w`rite and `q`uit.

If you don't like the process substitution bashism `<(...)` (but why wouldn't you like it?),

```
printf '%s\n' ',s/,/1,/' 'wq' | ed -s file
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this through awk also,

```
$ awk '{sub(/,/,"1,")}1' file
00011,mountain,a big rock
00021,tree,a tall plant
00031,whale,a big fish
00041,lion,a big cat
00051,iPhone,a small computer
```

Answer (score 1):

```
nawk -F"," '{$1=$1 1}1' OFS="," file
```